# Splitting models into different classes?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a ton of models. I mean a ton. Would it be possible to reorganize these models into a nicer format using a new Python package?

IE: Current -

```
myproject/
    web/
        models.py
```

IE: New -

```
myproject/
    web/
        models/
            __init__.py
            events.py
            registrations.py
            lessons.py
```

...and simply import them all in my `__init__.py` file? I'm kind of new to Python packages, will this essentially act the same as having a single `models.py` file?

Comment: I think this is always a good idea if you have more then one logical entity in a project. Also if you are writing managers for every model (maybe moving them to a managers.py file is a good idea too). I also do this with settings files so instead of having one large settings file I break it up into development.py, production.py, database.py, common.py and put them in a settings folder

Comment: This was an initial frustration I had with Django: you mean I really have to put 30 classes in _ONE FILE!?!_ As a recovering Java developer, this nearly broke my mind.

Comment: I spent a lot of time finding the best ways to go about getting a logical project structure together when I started with Django. Have a google around on 'django project structure' and you'll find some good articles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's a bit tedious: you will want to revise which imports to keep in each file, etc., but it's definitely possible.

You can also do it piecemeal, by renaming `models.py` to `models/__init__.py` (which shouldn't have any effect at all), and then moving stuff out one module at a time.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I hoped was possible.